# What is wrong with the implementation of this inversion count algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort, insertion-sort

I am doing a question on www.hackerrank.com and I have been stuck on it for days.

Here is the statement of the question https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insertion-sort. Basically, I have to count how many swaps occur in insertion sort for a given array in O(nlog(n)) time.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12637144/ Here is my submitted code. I use merge sort and count how many times each element is displaced. This code passes for more than half of the site's tests. When it fails it doesn't time out, and it doesn't have a compilation error or segmentation fault.

Furthermore, when I got the input for one of the failed test cases (Here is the input that it failed on the site http://paste.ubuntu.com/12637165/) and tested it with this variation of my code http://paste.ubuntu.com/12637127/ which actually runs the insertion sort algorithm counting the number of swaps along the way and checks it against the merge sort count, I pass all of the tests. Also, I have generated thousands of random test cases, and they also all pass using this test.

I don't think its a problem on the site's end because in the discussions for the problem other people seem to be passing the tests just fine without any questions or complaints. So maybe I am misunderstanding either the question or I am simply writing both the algorithm and the test cases for the algorithm wrong. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If n can be upto 100000, then the no. of inversions can be ~= n^2 / 2 which wont fit in a 32 bit integer. Try using a 64 bit integer for counting and for return value of mergeSort.

Comment: I thought that at first too and tested it, but it isn't true. The max value for a 32 bit signed int is 0x7fffffff which is 2,147,483,647. That's more than enough for all of the number ranges given.

Comment: Try this input. n = 100000 and the array is 100000, 99999 ... 1. The final result obviously wont fit even in a 32 bit unsigned int. Did you try changing the type of count variable and return type of mergeSort to long long and test it? Also, the final print statement matters too - you should use %lld instead of %d.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I think it was the change to lld in the print statement that made it work!